# A very basic exercise help-----Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to do this exercise

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

I already wrote the code but the result is not right and for my eyes its all good

Could somebody pls tell me whats wrong??
thx

```
    import java.util.Scanner
fun main(){
    var loop = 0
var score = Array<Int>(2){0}
val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
var alice:String = readLine().toString()
    var bob:String = readLine().toString()
    val numerosa: List<String> =  alice.split(" ")
    val numerosb:List<String> = bob.split(" ")
    for(a in 3..3) {

        when (numerosa[loop].toInt()) {
            in numerosb[loop].toInt() + 1..100 -> score[0] += 1
            in numerosb[loop].toInt() - 1..0 -> score[1] += 1
        }
        loop += 1
    }
println("${score[0]} ${score[1]}")

}
```

Comment: 1) What input are you providing? 2) What result are you getting? 3) What result are you expecting?

Comment: 5 6 7   /n 3 6 10   ))thats the input, 2 lines of 3 numbers each. Separated by 1 space. )))Im getting 0 0 
  ))))))))))Im expecting to get 1 1   in this case

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind most of your code, but `for a( in 3..3)` will loop exactly 0 times.

Comment: What is the point of participating in a challenge and cheating by asking others to complete it for you? And *the result is not right* is not a problem description unless you tell us what input you used, what result you expected from that input, and what your code produces instead.

Comment: Ken Im just learning and I just dont know what the problem is. I do it mainly to learn common is it seriously wrong ?

Comment: Robby oh I didnt know, I tought for (a in 3..3) would loop 3 times

Comment: Im sorry man I just started like 4 days ago in this programming world

Comment: @Juanmoreno range going from 3 to 3 has no element, will never loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it something like this, you have multiple variables which were not required so I cleaned up the code.

```kotlin
val score = Array(2) { 0 }
val aliceNumbers = readLine()!!.split(" ").map(String::toInt)
val bobNumbers = readLine()!!.split(" ").map(String::toInt)

require(aliceNumbers.size == 3 && bobNumbers.size == 3) { "There must be 3 numbers for each" }
require(!aliceNumbers.any { it !in 1..100 } || !bobNumbers.any { it !in 1..100 }) { "Numbers must be in range 1 to 100" }

for (a in 0..2) {
    if(aliceNumbers[a] > bobNumbers[a]) score[0] += 1
    if(aliceNumbers[a] < bobNumbers[a]) score[1] += 1
}
println("${score[0]} ${score[1]}")
```